# Who should our moderators be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, beta-phase, moderation

This site has been in public beta for a week, and it'll soon be time for us to get moderators. During the beta period, moderators are selected by Stack Exchange staff (there will be elections once the site graduates). This is all explained in the blog post [Moderators *pro tempore*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), which I invite you to read. Citing the most salient points:

> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

The purpose of this post is to seek out candidates. Are you interested in being involved in the site? Do you think you have the qualities outlined above? Then please manifest yourself! Have you noticed someone who you would like to see as a moderator? Then nominate that person. Some rules:

- Each nomination should be posted as a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.
- Self-nominations are okay, even encouraged.
- If the nomination was posted by a third party, the nominee should indicate whether they accept or decline by editing the answer. (It's ok to take some time to think about it!) Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- These nominations are not binding on either the nominees or Stack Exchange staff.

Comment: Does the moderator nominee have to have high reputation?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian High reputation isn't a firm requirement. Positive participation is a requirement, and usually that does translate into reputation, but someone who's done, say, a lot of edits and reviews but not posted much might be looked upon more favorably than someone who hasn't ever done anything but answer. Some technical competence is required but it's the “human qualities” that matter most.

Comment: Approximately how many mods do we need?

Comment: @Malabarba Sites normally have at least 3 (more if the traffic requires it). See the linked blog post.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not relevant anymore (also I think it should be locked as "historically signficant").

Comment: Leaving open for the moment pending clarification.  Moderator Pro Tem are pending elections.  Are we going to set up a new thread at the time of elections or should this be the list of nominations for the elections.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin This thread is to solicit candidates in the early beta and further replies would not be useful. When elections are held, there'll be a separate interface for nominations — there's one going on right now on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/election) if you want to know what it looks like. If more moderators are needed during the beta, SE staff will make a separate announcement if necessary.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the clarification.  In that case, closing.

Answer (score 37):

## [Malabarba](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/50/malabarba)

[image][image]
[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/228922.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/228922/malabarba?tab=accounts)

I confirm the nomination.

**Area 51 participation:** http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/28113/malabarba?tab=stats

**Blog posts reviewing or announcing the site**: I have an ongoing series of posts about questions here. Here are the links so far:

- [Auto-focus a Relevant File in Dired Buffers](http://endlessparentheses.com/auto-focus-a-relevant-file-in-dired-buffers.html)
- [Updating org-mode #+INCLUDE: statements on the fly](http://endlessparentheses.com/updating-org-mode-include-statements-on-the-fly.html)
- [Aggressive Auto-indentation](http://endlessparentheses.com/permanent-auto-indentation.html)
- [Longlines mode in LaTeX](http://endlessparentheses.com/longlines-mode-in-latex.html)

---

- **1st** by rep on Emacs SE
- 2nd by [votes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) (517), 2nd to [cast](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) more than 300 votes
- **1st** by [participation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation)
- **Very** active [reviewer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/50/gilles?tab=activity&sort=reviews) (178)
- **1st** by [meta participation](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation)
- **1st** by [editing](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all) (139)
- Actively [participated](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta?userid=50) in private beta
- Active [promoter](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer) of this site

Answer (score 28):

## [Gilles](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/25/gilles)

[image][image]
[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/164368.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/164368/gilles?tab=accounts)

- Note the total rep (summarized from rep on accounts having at least 200 reps) - **half a million**
- Already a moderator on 3 other Stack Exchange sites
- 4th user by rep on Emacs SE
- **1st** by [votes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) (589), **1st** to [cast](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) more than 300 votes
- 2nd by [participation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation)
- Active [reviewer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/25/gilles?tab=activity&sort=reviews) (105)
- The **1st** by silver badges - **9**
- 2nd by [meta participation](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation)
- 2nd by [editing](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all) (131)
- Actively [participated](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta?userid=25) in private beta

---

### Declined.

It's not that I have anything against Emacs.SE, but I'm already a moderator on three sites. That's enough. Let there be new blood.

Comment: You declined? Oh. No.

Answer (score 7):

## [Sigma](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/79/sigma)

[image][image]
[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/392509.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/392509/sigma?tab=accounts)

**Sorry, I have to decline.** I don't think I would do a particularly good job in any kind of official capacity, as I prefer operating in a "no strings attached" mode :)

Thanks though, happy to see my contribution is appreciated.

---

- 3rd user by rep on Emacs SE
- Active [reviewer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/79/sigma?tab=activity&sort=reviews) (85)
- [Voter](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) (54 votes)
- [Participates](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation) in meta
- [Editor](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors) (9 edits)
- Actively [participated](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta?userid=79) in private beta

Comment: This made me cry.

Comment: @Chantola, why?

Comment: @KingShimkus Because such a noble person genuinely declines being a moderator.

Answer (score 4):

### [King Shimkus](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/45/king-shimkus)

[image: profile for King Shimkus at Emacs Stack Exchange, Q&A for for those using, extending or developing emacs]


[image: profile for King Shimkus at Emacs Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for for those using, extending or developing emacs]


[profile for King Shimkus on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3967082.png?](http://stackexchange.com/users/3967082)

I love participating in the new Emacs Stack Exchange site! It is one of the few sites on Stack Exchange that I can contribute my knowledge. I also would like to thank Malabarba for nominating me and supporting me. It really means a lot coming from him. Thanks, And don't forget to vote!

---

> "Besides general participation, I noticed he's quite active as a tag
>   editor." - [Malabarba](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/50/malabarba)

- [Participated](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta?userid=45) in the beta.
- Currently 3rd in [Participation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation).
- Active [Voter](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters). (192)
- Active [Editor](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all). (110)
- An [Enthusiast](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/enthusiast?userid=45). ( I keep my Emacs.SE tab open 24/7 )
- First to earn [Investor](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/45/investor?userid=45), [Promoter](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/46/promoter?userid=45), and [Altruist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/48/altruist?userid=45).

Answer (score 3):

## [Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew)

[image]
[image]
[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/749092.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/749092/drew?tab=accounts)

Unsure if Drew himself is interested in this, but I'm putting it out there to find out what people think.

- **2nd** user by rep on Emacs SE (as of this writing)
- Active [reviewer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew?tab=activity&sort=reviews)
- [Editor](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors)
- [Participates](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation) in meta
- Actively [participated](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta?userid=105) in private beta
- Superlative: most likely to teach you more than you expected to learn.
- Superlative: has answered [the most questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/emacs/query/197083/users-with-most-answers) of any user here.

Comment: Agree especially on the first superlative: his answers commonly go above and beyond the call of duty.

Comment: @Drew Do you accept the nomination?

Answer (score 3):

## [Dan](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/253/dan)

[image]
[image]
[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/900487.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/900487/dan?tab=accounts)

- All time rank: **#6**
- One of only 97 users holding a [bronze tag badge for `emacs`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/492/emacs?userid=936762) on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936762/dan)
- [Actively participated](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta?userid=253) in the private beta
- [Participates](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation) in Meta
- [Editor](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors)
- [Voter](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) (151)
- [Asks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2861/504) [interesting](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2268/504) [questions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2706/504) and [provides](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3017/504) [great](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2529/504) [answers](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/623/504)
- **Always friendly and helpful**. Not afraid to [step in](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/how-do-i-get-my-initial-frame-to-be-the-desired-size/2270#comment2979_2270) when conflicts arise.

In [his own words](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2999/how-to-maximize-my-emacs-frame-on-start-up/3001#comment4135_3001):

> Happy to help in whatever way keeps this site going strong.

**Dan says**: I confirm the nomination, and am grateful that my contributions have been helpful in the past.  My value-added may be that I'm not a full-time (or even part-time) programmer, so I'm coming to Emacs for all the other great stuff we can do with it.  I suspect that's a non-trivial portion of the user base.